# error al intentar guardar imagen

Tags: python, excel, imagen

estoy intentando guardar una imagen proveniente de un archivo de excel y recibo este error, sinceramente no sé porqué es, utilizo el siguiente codigo

```
#leemos el excel de los días consecutivos con correctos e incorrectos en la ruta especificada
workbook_path=('B:\WFM - Compartida Lima\\02.Proceso 6 Dias\Resultado.xlsx') #ruta especificada 
excel = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application') #aplicación de excel
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(workbook_path) #abrimos el excel de la ruta workbook_path
sheet = wb.Sheets['RES'] #leemos la hoja RES
excel.visible = 1 
copyrange = sheet.Range('A1:E21') #rango a copiar para la imagen que se insertará en el cuerpo del correo
copyrange.CopyPicture(Appearance=1, Format=2) #copiamos la imagen
imagen = ImageGrab.grabclipboard().save('C:\\Users\\capenaloza\\Desktop\\AlertasAMZ\\informe.jpg') #guardamos la imagen en esta ruta
excel.quit()
```

me da el siguiente error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podría ayudarme indicándome a que se debe el error, o ayudándome a corregirlo? No doy aún con el problema, lo curioso es que funciona algunas veces pero vuelve y falla y se presenta este error.

Comment: `ImageGrab.grabclipboard()` tiene tipo NoneType, que daría a entender que no es lo que esperas que sea (una instancia de una clase que te permita correr el método `save`). Estás importando todo lo que necesitas (algo como `from PIL import Image, ImageGrab` que no vemos en tu fragmento de código)?

Comment: claro, mira, utilizo estos: 
*import os
import win32com.client as client
import pathlib
from PIL import ImageGrab*

por eso no entiendo porque no funciona